# Why is my file not being found? [Android]

Tags: android, file, bufferedreader

My file is located inside my package.

```
        bufferLine = "";
        fileName = "fulllist.txt";

        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((bufferLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {


            }   
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");               
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get this error:

> Unable to open file 'fulllist.txt'

Do I need to include a package name or something?  I tried using

```
System.err.println("Current directory is" + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

to debug but all that printed was

> Current directory is /

which is no help to me because I asume that means its searching inside the package, right?  if any additional information is needed please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the folder of your data directory (data/data/app.package.name/), use this:

```
String directory = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/";
```

To get a file stream of file in your assets folder, use this:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
```

Here's an example to parse the input stream to a String:

```
private  String getString(String filename)
    {


        String result = null;



        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();             
        try 
        {
            InputStream is = am.open(filename);
            int length = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            is.read(data);
            result = new String(data);
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

In case your text-file is actually a list of items, it might be better to scrub this text file all together, and instead use an array resource (usually placed in res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="months">
        <item>Month</item>
        <item>Jan</item>
        <item>Feb</item>
        <item>Mar</item>
        <item>Apr</item>
        <item>May</item>
        <item>Jun</item>
        <item>Jul</item>
        <item>Aug</item>
        <item>Sep</item>
        <item>Oct</item>
        <item>Nov</item>
        <item>Dec</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

Then in your code:

```
String[] list = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: 11-07 21:22:10.787: W/System.err(13237): Unable to open file '/data/data/com.example.anagram/fulllist.txt'

Comment: Where is your file exactly?

Comment: Yes, but where? what does this mean "inside your package"? Is it in your assets folder? in your resource folder? is it in some sub folder?

Comment: Its with my classes, in the same grouping

Comment: That's not the correct place to put a text file. It will not be copied when your app is installed. The source folder is use by the compiler, and unrelated files will be ignored. If you want to add a text file to your app and use it during runtime, you should add it to you assets folder, then open it like the 2nd example in this answer.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using an inputstream?  It seems difficult to get the data out that way.

Comment: No, but it's fairly simple to use the input stream to get your file as a string. Check my edit.

Comment: What if my file contains many lines and I want to put each line in a arraylist of strings?

Comment: Well, if your text file is actually a list of strings, you might consider rethinking it all together and instead of a text file, use an array resource (which you will place in your res/values folder).